# Blit() Performance dependent on screen rotation

Tags: mfc, windows-ce

I am developing an application for a WinCE 6.0 device in which there is a need to rotate the screen, so we are using the typical `ChangeDisplaySettingsEx()` API. and also I am drawing something on the View.

While blitting from the `memDC` to the main DC, it is taking 20ms for 700x300 pixels in Landscape mode, but in Portrait mode blitting a 450x450 block is taking 50 ms.

I am not able to determine why this is happening. Here is the device configuration :- 800x480 resolution. I am using Normal `Blt()` API for that.

Any suggestion will be helpful

Answer (score 2):

I know nothing about WinCE, but the performance difference is logical if the copy algorithm works line by line.

In one mode the layout of the pixels on the screen an in video RAM are identical. If that is the case, a line on screen corresponds to a number of consecutive memory addresses.

In portrait mode the algorithm needs to access a new memory location for each new pixel. Although the pixels sit right next to each others, the memory addresses to not.

Comment: Yep, this holds true in CE as well.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the drawing sequence to device screen is line by line vertically.
In Landscape mode , 480 lines to draw. And in Portrait mode 800 lines to draws.
Where scan one line will need more time.

Answer (score 0):

I've confronted this same issue and my solution was to roll my own rotated bitmap blit routine directly to the display buffer. BitBlt and StretchBlt are poorly written and have sat unchanged since the mid 1980s (I've seen the source code to the Windows GDI). It will still be slower to bitblt in the 'wrong' direction, but it doesn't have to be that slow. The issue is the small processor cache is being thrashed by writing to memory non-sequentially.